# How should I use an existing JavaScript library inside my Safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I want to use [Mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) inside my Safari extension so that the extension can capture keyboard shortcuts. But it does't seem to work. I am working on a small extension, which is entirely inside the Global.html file.

So far, I've tried:

1. `<script type="text/javascript" src="./mousetrap.min.js"></script>`
2. Injected script

Or is there another way to make a keyboard shortcut trigger something in a Safari extension? I just need one (it involves Cmd and Shift).

**UPDATE with solution**

For people from the future (do we have jetpacks yet?), this is what I did in the injected end script:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown, false);

function handleKeydown(e) {
    // If <my JS keyCode of choice> is pressed down, checks it Cmd and Shift were pressed
    if (e.keyCode == <my JS keyCode of choice> && e.metaKey && e.shiftKey) {
        safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('<someMessage>');
    }
}
```

And I put this in the `Global.html`:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

function handleMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.name == '<someMessage>') {
        someFunctionDefinedBelowThis();
    }
}
```

Comment: many shortcut, especially those using Cmd/Ctrl, are reserved and not possible to customize.

Comment: @dandavis No way to make it work even though my shortcut does not do anything at the moment? And Mousetrap works in Safari when put into websites. Surely there is no way for Safari to tell if Mousetrap is reserving keys.

Comment: does your shortcut work from mousetrap running a website? do any shortcuts work from the extension?

Comment: @dandavis The shortcuts on the [official website](http://craig.is/killing/mice) work. The second example is very similar to what I'm trying to do. It does get triggered on the website.

Comment: @dandavis It looks like other extensions use Mousetrap. They are much more complex than mine and I am new to all this so I cannot read them to understand. Maybe you can help? [Example 1](https://github.com/flipxfx/sVim/tree/master/sVim.safariextension), [Example 2](https://github.com/guyht/vimari/tree/master/vimari.safariextension).

Comment: You definitely need to include Mousetrap as an injected script. But then your global page can't access it directly, so you'll need a second injected script that interacts with Mousetrap, and then sends messages to the global page if necessary.

Comment: @MattSwain Ooh. That sounds promising. It looks like other extensions do something like this. I'll look at Apple's documentation and send messages that way. If I get it working before someone posts an answer, I'll update this post myself for people from the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a single shortcut, it might be simpler to implement entirely yourself.

In an injected script:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown, false);

function handleKeydown(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey) {
        safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('keyboard', e.which);
    }
}
```

This checks that the control key is down, but none of the other modifiers are. Then it dispatches a message to the global page when a second key is pressed while control is held.

Then in the global page:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

function handleMessage(msg) {
    if(msg.name == 'keyboard') {
        console.log(msg.message);
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(msg.message));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of that! But I tried exactly what you said and it does not work. Nothing prints to console. I tried injecting it as a start _and_ end script. But I'm sure you're close.